# How to change CommandTarget

Tags: c#, wpf, routed-commands

I have class `DesignerCanvas` where I have `RoutedCommand`.

```c#
public class DesignerCanvas
{
    public static RoutedCommand SelectAll = new RoutedCommand();

    public DesignerCanvas()
    {
        this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(DesignerCanvas.SelectAll, SelectAll_Executed));
        SelectAll.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.A, ModifierKeys.Control));
    }
}
```

In `ResourcesDictionary` I've got `MyToolbar` in this I've got buttons that have specify commands like this:

```c#
<Button Margin="3" Width="55" Style="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonBaseStyle}"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
            Command="{x:Static DesignerCanvas.SelectAll}"
            CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=MyDesigner} /">
```

And everything works perfect unless I don't close main window and than create it ones again with `new MainWindow().Show()`. All commands want to execute in old `DesignerCanvas` (from the original `MainWindow`) What can I do to change `CommandTarget` to new `DesignerCanvas` witch was created in new `MainWindow`?

**EDIT**

`MyDesigner` in `MainWindow`:

```c#
<s:DesignerCanvas
   Focusable="true"
   x:Name="MyDesigner"
   Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
   ContextMenu="{StaticResource DesignerCanvasContextMenu}"
   SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
   Margin="-2" />
```

Comment: Please show the code behind this binding: `CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=MyDesigner}`

Comment: @MareInfinitus that's it, I've got nothing more (exept `SelectAll_Executed`, but it's irrelevant)

Comment: I do not see the Element with the name "MyDesigner" which is used in code, especially in the Binding.

Comment: @MareInfinitus you're right! Sorry. Edited post ;)

Comment: Remarkable! I was about to ask the exact same question with the exact same code (from sukram's tutorial on codeproject). If I find an answer, I will post here.

Comment: @josh it will be great ;) thanks!